# How to save a json from dataframe with specific format?

Tags: json, pyspark

i'm trying to save the following pyspark dataframe to json:

```
ID VARIABLE_1
1      1
2      0
3      0
4      1
5      0
```

but i need the json to be like:

```
{ "1": {"VARIABLE_1": 1} }
{ "2": {"VARIABLE_1": 0} }
{ "3": {"VARIABLE_1": 0} }
{ "4": {"VARIABLE_1": 1} }
{ "5": {"VARIABLE_1": 0} }
```

When saving to json i get the following:

```
{ "ID":"1", "VARIABLE_1": 1} 
{ "ID":"2", "VARIABLE_1": 0} 
{ "ID":"3", "VARIABLE_1": 0} 
{ "ID":"4", "VARIABLE_1": 1} 
{ "ID":"5", "VARIABLE_1": 0}
```

i'm trying to save with

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("json").save(json_path)
```

i tried using create_map and got a dataframe like this:

```
NEW_COLUMN_NAME
{ "1": {"VARIABLE_1": 1} }
{ "2": {"VARIABLE_1": 0} }
{ "3": {"VARIABLE_1": 0} }
{ "4": {"VARIABLE_1": 1} }
{ "5": {"VARIABLE_1": 0} }
```

But when i try to save this new dataframe to json i get:

```
{"NEW_COLUMN_NAME":{"1":{"VARIABLE_1":1}}}
{"NEW_COLUMN_NAME":{"2":{"VARIABLE_1":0}}}
{"NEW_COLUMN_NAME":{"3":{"VARIABLE_1":0}}}
{"NEW_COLUMN_NAME":{"4":{"VARIABLE_1":1}}}
{"NEW_COLUMN_NAME":{"5":{"VARIABLE_1":0}}}
```

I don't really know what to do, someone have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: json format will contain the name and values, its not possible to drop one name (ID) and retain other name (VARIABLE_1) while saving as json format

Comment: Once you get your data in the format you wanted (using `create_map`) try using `.write.text(json_path)` to write the string to a file. Something like this: `df.select("NEW_COLUMN_NAME").write.text(json_path)`

Comment: when i try to write.text it says "Text data source does not support map" and if i try to Cast('string') it changes  from  { "1": {"VARIABLE_1": 1} }  to  [1-> [VARIABLE_1-> 0]]

Comment: My spark is version 2.4

Comment: I'm not able to test on 2.4 but does `to_json` work on the `MapType()` column? `df.select(to_json("NEW_COLUMN_NAME")).write.text(json_path)`. If not, it's a little hacky but you can build the string manually: `df.select(concat(lit('{"'), "ID", lit('":{"VARIABLE_1":"'), "VARIABLE_1", lit('"}}')).write.text(json_path)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i fixed the issue:

-Used collect() to collect the create_map dataframe

-Used for to make a dictionary with every row of the dataframe

-Used json.dumps with the dictionary

-Saved using open(path, "w")